# Facilitate switching between latex (eps) and pdflatex (png/pdf) in the same paper

Tags: pdftex, eps, png, dvips

I have to hand in a postscript version of my paper for a conference, so I have to use `latex` instead of `pdflatex`.

As I may later need a different version, I would like to write the paper in such a way that switching between the formats is easy.

What is the best way to do this, considering that one program needs `png`/`pdf` graphic files, while the other only allows `eps`?

**Edit adressing comment**:
Until now, I only have figures in png and pdf. I am aware of manual conversion tools between the graphic formats. However, I don't know of a way to do an automatic conversion of all used graphics within a tex file. Thus, converting the whole paper is very labour-intensive as of now.

Comment: Do you have (or can you generate) graphics in both formats?

Comment: As @JosephWright writes, if you just have `.eps` and `.png` or `.pdf` versions of the gfx files, then just use `\includegraphics{file}` instead of `\includegraphics{file.pdf}` and `pdflatex` will choose the version it supports while `latex` chooses the `.eps`.

Comment: In addition to what @daleif says, if you have EPS versions of everything then a modern TeX system will auto-convert to PDF as required. So what I'm trying to get at is can you arrange to have that full set of EPS graphics?

Comment: As for the comment: that is just the way it is. I personally do not trust the automatic conversions from within LaTeX as it may end up hiding warnings from the conversion tool.

Comment: It also depends on which OS you are using, if you are on Linux or Mac it is really easy to make a script that converts a bunch of gfx from one format to another.

Comment: So the answer to the question (easiest way to facilitate both?) is to have all graphic files in just eps, even for raster graphics?

Comment: I would not say so. I would keep it in `.pdf` and `.png` and when the time comes, make `.eps` versions even if it is tedious work. BTW: Do you need to hand in the sources or just a PS version? Because then it might be as easy as just converting the PDF to PS at the end.

Comment: Hadn't thought of the reverse conversion. Thanks to both of you! Would one of you sum up the comments in an answer, so I can accept it?

Comment: Classic [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the only requirement is that you provide a `.ps` version of your document. just convert the `.pdf` to `.ps` at the very end. (if odd in these PDF times).

As for a general method of being able to use `latex` and `pdflatex` on a single source

1. have `.eps` and (`.pdf` or `.png` or `.jpg`) versions of each gfx
2. indclude without extention, i.e. `file`, not `file.ext`. [1]

[1] If your gfx names contain spaces or multiple `.`, remember the `grffile` package.